# Accessing injected properties results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, cdi, quarkus

This is the first time for me working with Quarkus and CDI and I think I'm getting it wrong.

In my application users can download some files. I'd like to control how many files are being downloaded simultaneously. I thought I could do this by creating a bean with `@ApplicationScoped` annotation, forcing instantiation at startup, and then injecting it wherever I need to know how many files are currently downloading.

This is what I managed to do:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class DownloadState {
    private int downloadingFiles;

    void startup(@Observes StartupEvent event) {
        setDownloadingFiles(0);
        System.out.println("downloading files: " + downloadingFiles);
    }

    public int getDownloadingFiles() {
        return downloadingFiles;
    }

    public void setDownloadingFiles(int downloadingFiles) {
        this.downloadingFiles = downloadingFiles;
    }

    public void incrementDownloadingFiles() {
        downloadingFiles++;
    }

    public void decrementDownloadingFiles() {
        downloadingFiles--;
    }
}
```

Doing this I can see the log at startup saying "downloading files: 0", so I know the class has been instantiated.

I try to access the number of downloading files here:

```java
public class Downloader {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Downloader.class);

    @Inject
    DownloadState downloadState;

    private Dotenv dotenv = Dotenv.configure()
        .directory("../")
        .filename(".env.local")
        .load();

    private String fileName = dotenv.get("DOWNLOAD_PATH");
    private String url;

    public Downloader(String url, String fileName) {
        this.url = url;
        this.fileName += fileName;
    }

    public void downloadProduct() {

        LOG.info("Downloading Files: " + downloadState.getDownloadingFiles());
        //...
    }
}
```

Whenever downloadProduct is called a NullPointerException is thrown on the line `LOG.info("Downloading Files: " + downloadState.getDownloadingFiles());`

Am I getting CDI totally wrong? Any help is really appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're calling the `Downloader` constructor directly -- in which case, indeed no injection will happen and your `downloadState` will be `null`. Dependency injection is "contagious" -- you have to use it everywhere.

In your case, I'd probably just make `Downloader` also `@ApplicationScoped`, inject it everywhere you use it, and probably move the `url` and `fileName` parameters from constructor to `downloadProduct`. Actually at that point, the number of `downloadingFiles` could also be in `Downloader`. (Also note that it can be accessed from multiple threads -- so I'd probably use an `AtomicInteger` for `downloadingFiles`.)

All in all, something like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Downloader {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Downloader.class);

    private final AtomicInteger downloadingFiles = new AtomicInteger(0);

    private final String downloadPath = Dotenv.configure()
        .directory("../")
        .filename(".env.local")
        .load()
        .get("DOWNLOAD_PATH");

    public void downloadProduct(String url, String fileName) {
        String path = downloadPath + fileName;

        int current = downloadingFiles.incrementAndGet();
        LOG.info("Downloading Files: " + current);
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I previously "solved" my problem through an eager singleton but I like this approach more! 
By the way, I'm not really sure if and why CDI is better, I'll investigate further. 
Thanks again :)